# Children component's props are not updated when the parent component start as null

Tags: reactjs

```js
// 1 - Parent - Wrong
render() {
const { record } = this.state;
if (!record) { return null; }
return (
  <div>
    <p>Now this is visible</p>
    <Children id={record.id};
  </div>
  );
}

// 2 - Parent - Right
render() {
  const { record } = this.state;
  const recordId = record ? record.id : null;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Now this is visible</p>
      <Children id={recordId};
    </div>
  );
}

// Children
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  console.log(nextProps.id);
}
```

> If the state becomes: this.state = { record: { id: 'demo' } }

Writing the code the first approach, nextProps is always undefined in the Children's componentWillReceiveProps even if the Parent record becomes visible because it received a new state.

While the second works as it should.

Why does the first work incorrectly?

Comment: Can you revise this? It's not clear what the question is

Comment: Yes sorry I am new here, the question was why children don't receive the props when I use the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [official document](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops), React doesn't call `componentWillReceiveProps` with initial props during mounting. It only calls this method if some of component's props may update.

I had a workaround for your problems and created the following fiddle for the solution. It should solve all your problems.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/4o7o6cmw/4/

Comment: Thanks, updating the state again in the callback is a nice workaround.
What do you suggest where should I listen for the prop update in the Children component?

Comment: You can use `componentDidMount` for initial listening of props. After that, you can listen from `componentWillReceiveProps`. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4o7o6cmw/6/).